# Model.updateOne() is not updating all fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, fastify

I am trying to perform a PATCH update on a MongoDB document. I retrieve the existing document like this with Mongoose:

```js
const ratePlan = await RatePlan.findOne({
  _id: req.params.id,
})
```

The following work correctly to update the model using the fields in the HTTP request (`req.body`):

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
  ratePlan[key] = value
}
await ratePlan.save()

// - OR -

await RatePlan.replaceOne(
  { _id: ratePlan._id },
  {
    ...ratePlan.toObject(),
    ...req.body,
  },
  {
    overwriteDiscriminatorKey: true,
    runValidators: true,
  },
)
```

However the following does not update a specific field that is an array of objects (it only updates the text and numeric fields):

```js
await RatePlan.updateOne({ _id: ratePlan._id }, req.body, {
  overwriteDiscriminatorKey: true,
  runValidators: true,
})
```

Why would it update some fields but not others?

Note: The `RatePlan` model contains two discriminators, `'parent'` and `'child'` with the `discriminatorKey` of `'kind'`. The field it does not update is only present on the `'parent'` kind. The document being updated is also `'parent'` kind.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that you are passing the array? The replaceOne() will find one and replace it entirely with new data. If for any reason you are sending something a tiny bit different, it's going to be changed.

I had a similar problem. And it turns out I was giving back two set of {} which made the entire field to be changed to nothing. So I ended up with an ID and nothing else.

can you try:

```
await RatePlan.updateOne({ _id: ratePlan._id }, {req.body}, {


overwriteDiscriminatorKey: true,
runValidators: true,
    })
```